# Replace and position text in text placeholder

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The code replaces my font Size.

```vb
Sub changeFont()
For Each aSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each aShape In aSlide.Shapes
If aShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
If aShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
If aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Franklin Gothic Demi" Then
If aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 40 Then
      aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = Replace(aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size, 40, 25)
End If
End If
End If

End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Apart from this I need to align my Text box to:

```
.Top=23  
.Left=44  
.Height=44
```

How do I position my Text holder?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Sub changeFont()
    Dim aSlide As Slide, aShape As Shape
    For Each aSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each aShape In aSlide.Shapes
            If aShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
                If aShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    If aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Franklin Gothic Demi" Then
                        If aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 40 Then
                              aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = Replace(aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size, 40, 25)
                              aShape.Top = 23
                              aShape.Left = 44
                              aShape.Height = 44
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help . There are some additional spaces to the left of my text which  I Need to remove I am trying to remove this 
using .wordwrap and Auto fit but the additional spaces is not being deleted. 

It would be grateful if you could please help with that. 

Thanks

Comment: @DilpreetSingh, add aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Trim(aShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) right before the aShape.Top = 23 command. If what I posted answers your question, then you should mark it as answered.

Comment: Hi Michaels , but the code metioned is not working and giving in error after run

Comment: I am currently using this code to establish . However what I have just discovered that some of the text in text placeholder has some indentation which should be 

Before text = 0 cm
Special = None
Alignment = Left


Please help to incorporate the same in the subroutine to establish the same.